# How to install sqlite3 on Debian running Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, debian

I have a debian vm on my windows pc that runs nodejs the problem is that `sqlite3` won't install on my application (mediacenterjs) but installs perfectly globally.

Here is part of my log file `npm-debug.log`:

```
/opt/mediaCenter1/node_modules/.staging/node-pre-gyp-445d3086
4883 info lifecycle node-pre-gyp@0.6.14~install: node-pre-gyp@0.6.14
4884 silly lifecycle node-pre-gyp@0.6.14~install: no script for install, continuing
4885 silly install sqlite3@3.1.1 /opt/mediaCenter1/node_modules/.staging/sqlite3-f2e19105
4886 info lifecycle sqlite3@3.1.1~install: sqlite3@3.1.1
4887 verbose lifecycle sqlite3@3.1.1~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle false
4888 verbose lifecycle sqlite3@3.1.1~install: PATH: /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/opt/mediaCenter1/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin:/opt/mediaCenter1/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/root/.npm-global/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin:/usr/lib/git-core:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
4889 verbose lifecycle sqlite3@3.1.1~install: CWD: /opt/mediaCenter1/node_modules/sqlite3
4890 silly lifecycle sqlite3@3.1.1~install: Args: [ '-c', 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build' ]
4891 silly lifecycle sqlite3@3.1.1~install: Returned: code: 1 signal: null
4892 info lifecycle sqlite3@3.1.1~install: Failed to exec install script
4893 verbose unlock done using /root/.npm/_locks/staging-fbc9d3a61073e2fa.lock for /opt/mediaCenter1/node_modules/.staging
4894 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
4895 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
4896 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
4897 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
4898 silly install printInstalled
4899 warn mediacenterjs@0.1.3 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
4900 verbose stack Error: sqlite3@3.1.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
4900 verbose stack Exit status 1
4900 verbose stack at EventEmitter. (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:242:16)
4900 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
4900 verbose stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
4900 verbose stack at ChildProcess. (/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
4900 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
4900 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
4900 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
4900 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
4901 verbose pkgid sqlite3@3.1.1
4902 verbose cwd /opt/mediaCenter1
4903 error Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
4904 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/root/.npm-global/bin/npm" "install" "sqlite3"
4905 error node v6.2.0
4906 error npm v3.10.5
4907 error code ELIFECYCLE
4908 error sqlite3@3.1.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
4908 error Exit status 1
4909 error Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.1 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
4909 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
4909 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
4909 error not with npm itself.
4909 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
4909 error node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
4909 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
4909 error npm bugs sqlite3
4909 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
4909 error npm owner ls sqlite3
4909 error There is likely additional logging output above.
4910 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the command `npm` to install `sqlit3` , a detailled tutorial is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3):

```
npm install --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=ia32 --target=$(NODE_WEBKIT_VERSION)
```

Answer (score 0):

In debian

```
sudo apt-get install node-sqlite3
```